# How to place a variable inside of an icon class on angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, variables, tags, icons

I want to put an icon on my page (which is inside of an `*ngfor`), f.i:

`<i class="var"></i>`

and I want to place a variable (which is given by my service class) where it is written 'var' in order to place different icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class can be inputted with `class="{{ your_variable }}"` or you can do `[class]="your_variable"`, you can also use `ngClass`

Comment: The `[class]="your_variable"` worked well. I found out I was referencing the variable to the wrong class as well. Thanks!